# sql.Rows memory usage when select query returns many rows

Tags: mysql, database, go

I want to write the results of a complex select query to a csv format file in Golang.
The rows returned from the query will be in the order of millions, and I want to conserve RAM, meaning I do not want the millions of rows on memory.
I'm using github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql.

When for example GORM returns [sql.Rows](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows) from https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#DB.Rows, do I understand correctly that not all rows are in memory,
and there's some buffer allocated in database/sql and as I call [rows.Scan](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows.Scan) to map the row into a Go struct and [write](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv#Writer.Write) it to a [csv.Writer](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv#Writer), the memory usage of the program doesn't change too much?

Can you explain and point me to official documents that describe this memory usage behavior?

Comment: You can make MySQL engine saves the records to CSV file direct. Add `INTO OUTFILE 'CsvFullFileName'` to the end of your queries. This may depends on user permission.

Comment: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/master/rows.go#L197-L198

Comment: @Ehab Right, I know.

Comment: @mkopriva so there's no buffer and when I call rows.Scan, database/sql calls go-sql-driver/mysql rows.Next and that just reads from network? Thanks I can accept if you can post an answer.